# How to get Firefox to store values for fields which it normally won't?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I have a web bank site. Where I pass through 2 steps:

1. Enter my login into the form with 1 text field and submit it
2. Enter 2 passwords into the 2-nd form: 1 is rarely changed and stored on my machine, another is for 1 session and sent to my mobile phone.

As [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/wont-remember-addresses-phone-numbers-text) says, firefox can remember the form fields. And I checked Preferences -> Privacy -> History remember search and form history checkbox is ticked.

Now I work like this:

1. Open the first form on site
2. Open file with login/pass for the webbank.
3. Copy the login from the file to clipboard
4. Paste it into the 1-st form and submit it.
5. Copy the password from the file to clipboard
6. Put it into the 1-st field
7. Get the temporary password from SMS
8. Put it into the 2-nd field
9. Submit the 2-nd form.

As I am the only person, using this computer, I'd like the save time and make firefox remember the values for login and password for me. So my actions would be like this:

1. Open the first form on site
2. login is already there, I just submit the form
3. Get the temporary password from SMS
4. Put it into the 2-nd field (the first already has the password)
5. Submit the 2-nd form.

So I had 5 actions instead of 9.

Comment: A form element on a web page can specify that autocompletion should be disabled on that field. I'm guessing that is what's going on here. If so, maybe you can look into using Greasemonkey or something like that to tinker with the DOM, but it'll be fragile at best and significantly increase the attack surface. If the bank finds out you've done that and something ever happens to your account, expect them to throw a fit about it, even if it wasn't instrumental in allowing a third party access.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling No, it doesn't seem, that they turned off the autocompletion in that forms. Here is the form tag from the page: `<form id="j_id_2_2k:loginForm" name="j_id_2_2k:loginForm" method="post" action="/scoring/login.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`, autocomplete attribute is not set.

Comment: Check the form *element*, not the *form*. Also, I think there are special rules for pages accessed over HTTPS. In any case, it's only a guess based on what (little) I know of Firefox's behavior.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Login is also ok: `<input id="j_id_2_2k:login" name="j_id_2_2k:login" type="text" value="" maxlength="20" class="login" accesskey="Login" tabindex="1" />`